# Google Sheets - find a value in a range and return data from another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m stuck trying to create a Google Sheets formula that searches a range for a value, and when the value is found returns the value of column a on the row where the value is found.

Ie: my range is c2:y199. The value to search for is serial# 0001-0010. If the value is found, I want to return the value of column A (owner) “Jones” in the row where the value was found. I would like to be able to do this on two sheets at the same time. Lookup is no help since my value won’t always be in the first column of the range (column C).

Comment: [XLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947?hl=en) can do that.

Comment: You're looking for `XLOOKUP`

Comment: I’ve looked at xlookup, and am trying to understand how this solves my issue when my lookup range is more than a single row or column.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & work out a solution. You may also use the [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by docs community forum for ease of sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Use of XLOOKUP

```
=XLOOKUP(A13;$C$2:$C$6;$A$2:$A$6;0;)
```

Parameters:

1. (A13): This is the cell containing the value you are trying to find. In your case the cell that holds the value `serial# 0001-0010`.
2. ($C$2:$C$6): The range to search. In you case `c2:y199`
3. ($A$2:$A$6): The range which is use to determine the returned value. In you case `a2:a199`, when `c42` matches it will return the value of `a42`.
4. (0): The value returned when no match was found.

Answer (score 1):

index(range_of_return_value,match(value_to_look_for,Range_where_to_look_for_given_value,0))

INDEX(A2:Y199,MATCH("serial# 0001-0010",C2:Y199,0))

This should look for "serial# 0001-0010" in C2:Y199 and then bring the value of the same row of A2:Y199

I recommend that instead of "serial# 0001-0010" you use another cell, say D1, and in D1 you paste the serial number you want to search. This will allow you to change the serial number and get the name without changing the formula

D1: "serial# 0001-0010"
D2: INDEX(A2:Y199,MATCH(D1,C2:Y199,0))